# Deploying Azure Webjobs from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: azure, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment, azure-webjobs

Please guide me to setup the procedure how to deploy the azure web jobs from Jenkins Pipeline. I have gone through the google of searching the documentation but couldn't able to make it.

Comment: Does this article help you [Deploy to Azure App Service by using the Jenkins plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/deploy-jenkins-app-service-plugin) ?

Comment: This articles explains about the Deployment of web application from the Jenkins. My use case is about deploying the azure web jobs from Jenkins Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

After many tests I did it by adding the **OutputPath** parameter in the deploy script and deleting the folder before. The script looks like this:

```
dir('Publish'){
    deleteDir() 
}
bat "\"${tool 'Your MS Build'}\" Path_To_Project.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:OutputPath=Publish\\ /p:PublishProfile=path_to_web_job_publish_settings.pubxml /p:Password=your_password"
```

Comment: Do you know what the significance was of deleting the publish directory before running the bat line?