# Azure webjobs publish from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-webjobs

I wasn´t able to find out much on internet about this. But I have a jenkins jobs that deploys a .net webapp using plugin azureWebAppPublish like follows. After the .net app is build in previous step in same pipeline I have following stage

```
stage ('publish to azure ') {


            azureWebAppPublish appName: "webapp-A",
                    azureCredentialsId: "jenkins-login",
                    publishType: "file",
                    filePath: "**/*.*",
                    resourceGroup: "webapp-rg"
                   
    }
```

I know that this by default deploys the files webapp in: home\site\wwwroot
In fact When I access there over console in azure I see the files deplyed.

Everything ok so far, files are deployed successfully in webapp. But now I would like to  publish also a webjob in same webapp.

I created it first by publishing it from visual studio. Right click, publish the wbjob and that´s it ,  the web job is running in azure in that webap. Thinig is that I would like to do it from the pipeline now. I saw that after I created the webjob, Inside `home\site\wwwroot` a folder was created, called: D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\Jobs\Continuous\service.webjobs(all files of that my webjob)
so there are all the files I would like to update.

but I don´t know how to do this same way using azureWebAppPublish as I used for webapp. indicating destination path for webjob files.

I used this and job run successfully

```
stage ('publish webjob ') {
    
    
                azureWebAppPublish appName: "webapp-A",
                        azureCredentialsId: "jenkins-login",
                        publishType: "file",
                        filePath: "**/*.*",
                        resourceGroup: "webapp-rg"
                        sourceDirectory: "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/servicestest/Services.WebJob/"
                        targetDirectory: "app_data/Jobs/Continuous/webjobtest1"
        }
```

but no update in app_data/jobs/contiues/webjobtest1 was made in fact, the job run ok and the webapp was updated and no the webjob

How can I update webjobs using jenkins? has someone did this sometime?

I see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61060632/deploying-azure-webjobs-from-jenkins-pipeline) but honestly it´s not quite clear how is it done.

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb but I looked at [File Command](https://github.com/jenkinsci/azure-app-service-plugin/blob/d07ddc5d8cfd8c796b05e4236a81cb9a2054f22d/src/main/java/com/microsoft/jenkins/appservice/commands/FileDeployCommand.java#L46) for the Azure App Service plugin. Check for deployment log to see if it found your .zip in your source folder. That should at least show if where the zip file is being pick up. According to this [doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/azure-app-service/)

> targetDirectory (optional) Target directory relative to the site root. Type: String

so your path may not be getting translated correctly. But to be honest, I'm not even sure how `targetDirectory` is [being used](https://github.com/jenkinsci/azure-app-service-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/jenkins/appservice/commands/FileDeployCommand.java) by the plugin for file deployment.

If the logs don't reveal anything, I suggest using a CLI plugin that will allow your [deploy your webjob through curl](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-a-zip-file-or-url).

Comment: Hey!, tried this but It didn´t upload anything. λ curl -X POST -u $myuser https://mywebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy -T files.zip
Enter host password for user '$myuser:

I didn´t get any error also. It got running for some seconds and returned empty prompt with no output. check in the full path of webjob but didn´t get any file updated. Did you try this method?

Comment: Use PUT mywebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuous/webjobtest1 for your REST endpoint.

Comment: I finally make it work with this: https://github.com/gabrieljoelc/proto-azure-pgp/blob/master/deploy.sh